# What's the ordering on team members?

Tags: support, old-teams

I can't work out how members of teams are ordered on the team's home page.

For example, if you look at the [Charcoal](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/52) team, there are 6 members. Here they are in order, with their names, IDs and join dates.

```
|  Username  |   ID    |        Join Date        |
|------------+---------+-------------------------|
| ArtOfCode  | 3160466 | May 21 '16 at 15:40:20Z |
| Yvette     | 3956566 | May 21 '16 at 15:44:38Z |
| hichris123 | 2581872 | Nov 09 '15 at 21:04:37Z |
| Undo       | 1849664 | Nov 09 '15 at 19:00:14Z |
| Andy       |  189134 | Nov 09 '15 at 19:43:35Z |
| ProgramFOX | 2619912 | Nov 09 '15 at 19:45:40Z |
```

If you can figure out what order those are in, you're doing better than I am.

Comment: Note that you don't appear first when I view it...

Comment: I see yvette, artofcode, hicris, andy, undo, programfox

Comment: what is meant with team?

Comment: @Zaibis the Teams beta feature. Follow the link for an example.

Comment: You order the team members, they take about 6-8 weeks to dispatch.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Users are sorted by "being the current user" and then by Last Access Date. Here's the code:

```
var members = t.Members
               .Where(tm => tm.User != null)
               .OrderBy(tm => tm.UserId != Current.User.Id)
               .ThenByDescending(tm => tm.User.LastAccessDate)
               .ToList();
```

Comment: What was the reasoning for sorting this way rather than, say, alphabetically or most recently joined?

Comment: @TylerH Pure speculation, but maybe because the most active would be the most reachable if you wanted to contact someone?

Comment: @jpmc26 the most active isn't the same as the last active, don't you think ?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub *Most* of the time, the people who were most recently on will be the most active people, simply by virtue of them being on the most. It's a "good enough" heuristic that avoids having to build an entire framework around analyzing the user's history of activity. It's a pretty good trade off, imo. ;)

Comment: @jpmc26 It's my understanding that this is the most recent member to visit the Team page, not the most recent member to log onto the site. It would be a little more useful (though not much) if it were the most recent member to log into the site.

Answer (score 24):

As rene pointed out in comments, it's ordered on the last seen timestamp. In the moment of writing it looks like this:

- hichris123, last seen 9 mins ago
- ArtOfCode, last seen 33 mins ago
- Andy, last seen 37 mins ago
- Undo, last seen 2 hours ago
- Yvette, last seen 3 hours ago
- ProgramFOX, last seen May 18 at 17:43